# Arquivo .keystore e .jks Android

Tags: android

Percebi que a Google tem o serviço [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), que é possível substituir a minha chave com a chave do google.

Para isso devo seguir uns passos que é:

1. Faça o download da ferramenta PEPK para exportar e criptografar sua chave privada.
2. Use o comando abaixo para executar a ferramenta que exportará e criptografará sua chave privada. Certifique-se de substituir os argumentos destacados em negrito. Em seguida, digite as senhas da chave e da keystore nas solicitações.

   $ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=**foo.keystore** --alias=**foo** --output=encrypted_private_key_path --encryptionkey=*chave criptografada*
3. Faça o upload da sua chave privada de assinatura de app criptografada.
4. Gere uma nova chave de upload. Siga estas instruções para gerar uma nova chave.
5. Exporte o certificado da chave de upload gerada recentemente para o formato PEM. Certifique-se de substituir os argumentos destacados em negrito.

   **$ keytool -export -rfc -keystore upload-keystore.jks -alias upload
   -file upload_certificate.pem**
6. Faça o upload do certificado da sua chave de upload para fazer o registro no Google.

Só que eu parei na segunda porque não tenho o arquivo .keystore (pelo menos, eu acho) eu tenho o jks que eu criei no ato da criação do apk assinado.

A pergunta:

O arquivo .jks pode ser esse .keystore ? Ou tenho que gerar esse arquivo?

Comment: amigo, estava com as mesmas dúvidas talvez isso aqui possa ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103025

Answer (score 0):

.keystore ou .jks são apenas variações de um mesmo tipo de arquivo. Existe também a possibilidade desse arquivo ser criado sem nenhuma extensão, pois é um tipo de arquivo que fica implícito pelo Java (Mas não recomendo fazer isso! Sempre crie-o com extensão para melhor identifica-lo quando precisar). Espero que tenha ajudado.